# ArrayList<Integer>, trying to find average of entered values

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Trying to find the average of the integers entered as input into the list.
Cant figure out how, im getting an error saying that it can't find symbol in
in the line total = total + in;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import type.lib.*;

public class Lists

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintStream print = new PrintStream(System.out);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> bag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        print.println("Enter your integers");
        print.println("(Negative=sentinel)");
        int total = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (int in = scan.nextInt(); in > 0; in = scan.nextInt());
        {
            total = total + in;
            count = count + 1;
        }

        double x = total / count;
        print.println("The average is: " + x);
    }
}
```

also, is there an easy way to output the numbers above average divided with a comma?

Comment: read compilation errors and look for mistake around the error position, not just go directly to SO :/

Comment: also, is there an easy way to display the numbers above average with a comma?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the semi-colon after the `for` loop:

```
for (int in = scan.nextInt(); in > 0; in = scan.nextInt())
```

The reason `in` is not defined for the compiler is that the semi-colon would de-scope its definition by acting as an empty body of the `for` loop.

Comment: I would add that `x` doesn't contain the right value since `total/count` is calculated as integer operation and its result cast to double. That line should be changed to `double x = (double)total / count;`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have ; after for loop...

```
for (int in = scan.nextInt(); in > 0; in = scan.nextInt())//remove ; here
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `;`  from your loop.

```
for (int in = scan.nextInt(); in > 0; in = scan.nextInt());
```

**change to**

```
for (int in = scan.nextInt(); in > 0; in = scan.nextInt())
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of a for loop is:

```
for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update)
{
   //Statements
}
```

You have added semicolon `;` so it's become empty body for `for` loop. you have to remove the **semicolon** after `for (int in = scan.nextInt(); in > 0; in = scan.nextInt())` line in your code.

Modified Code : I am providing code after modification.

```
public class Lists

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintStream print = new PrintStream(System.out);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> bag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        print.println("Enter your integers");
        print.println("(Negative=sentinel)");
        int total = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (int in = scan.nextInt(); in > 0; in = scan.nextInt()){
            total = total + in;
            count = count + 1;
        }

        double x = total / count;
        print.println("The average is: " + x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code requires two changes:

1.You need to remove the semicolon after for loop which is making loop useless and all the iterations you want to do won't take place.

2.The second change is you need to cast one of the variables total or count to double to avoid truncation else your results will always be integers.

The modified code is as follows:

```js
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import type.lib.*;

public class Lists

{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  PrintStream print = new PrintStream(System.out);
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  List<Integer> bag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  print.println("Enter your integers");
  print.println("(Negative=sentinel)");
  int total = 0;
  int count = 0;
  
  for (int in = scan.nextInt(); in > 0; in = scan.nextInt())
  {
   total = total + in;
   count = count + 1;
  }
  
  double x = (double)total / count;
  print.println("The average is: " + x);
 }
}
```